# Build maven project inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, maven

I'm having some problems while trying to build a mvn project inside a Docker container. Everytime I try to build using the following Dockerfile, I get this error:

```
[10/10] COPY target/*.jar app.jar:
------
lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount9100795/target: no such file or directory
```

My current Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.1-openjdk-17 as builder
COPY src /tmp/src/
COPY pom.xml /tmp/
WORKDIR /tmp/
RUN mvn clean install


FROM maven:3.8.1-openjdk-17
WORKDIR /tmp/app
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Comment: try to use an absolute path to app.jar. Maybe the copy and entrypoints uses different working directories

Answer (score 0):

I've found the correct configurations for the dockerfile and relative paths. Since I've set the WORKDIR for the buider as `/tmp/` my target folder was being generated at `/tmp/target/`, so specifying the source files with the `---from=builder` tag, and updating the path, I was able to succesfully copy the `.jar` file

My current working dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.1-openjdk-17 as builder
COPY src /tmp/src/
COPY pom.xml /tmp/
WORKDIR /tmp/
RUN mvn clean install


FROM maven:3.8.1-openjdk-17
COPY --from=builder /tmp/target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).